# does Visual Studio 2010 not have a "join lines" keyboard shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

does Visual Studio 2010 not have a "join lines" keyboard shortcut?

EDIT - That is when on line X anywhere, I hit a shortcut key once, and then line X+1 joins to line X (eliminating CR between them so to speak)

Comment: What do you mean? Deleting at lines' beginning/end will join two lines. What are you thinking of doing?

Comment: That is when on line X anywhere, I hit a shortcut key once, and then line X+1 joins to line X (eliminating CR between them so to speak)

Comment: @Greg- It appears your three identical comments need to be merged not joined. :-)

Comment: I'm not going to do the legwork for you, but you might look into how VsVim implements the `J` operator to join lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I far as I know it does not.

However, you can create and save a new VS macro using the following code:

```
Sub JoinLines()
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Delete")
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine()
End Sub
```

and [assign a keyboard shortcut to it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0003t62%28VS.80%29.aspx)  (like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>)

This code will join the current line with the one right below it.

Comment: I think he wants to join with the line below it, meaning that you can probably eliminate the first 2 lines of the macro.

Comment: Assuming he's asking because he's a vim user, you'd actually want: EndOfLine, delete, insert a space (I think), move left one character.

Comment: this looks good - just stuck trying to figure out in VS2010 how to do the keyboard assignment to the JoinLines Sub method...

Comment: @Greg- `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard`.  In text field for `Show commands containing:`, simply type `JoinLines` and your new macro should display.  Then in `Press shortcut keys`, type `Ctrl + j`, click `Assign`, and finally `OK`. It should work after that.

Comment: Macros are not supported in Visual Studio 2012/2013: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062515/can-i-record-play-macros-in-visual-studio-2012-2013

Comment: How do I make a macro in VS Code?

Answer (score 19):

This is not exactly what you want, but I find it useful nonetheless.

If you are at the end of the first line, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to join the next line and delete any white space between them.

You still have to be at the end of the line, but this will work on virtually every editor, without any modifications.

Answer (score 16):

I use the [CodeMaid](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496) extension for this, it provides a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> shortcut to join lines (and some other useful things too)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the join feature to act like Vim (pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>) then use this macro that joins, inserts space and places cursor after the space:

```
Sub JoinLines()
    Dim textSelection As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
    With textSelection
        .EndOfLine()
        .Insert(" ")
        .Delete(1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Just assign it to something like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> (as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> are taken).

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 (am on Version 16.8.4) now has a shortcut inbuilt yayy! 
 It's `shift+alt+ L` & then `shift+alt+ J`

I remember the shortcut thinking of Lines(L) - Join(J) (it could have been J ... L but ah well, grouping i think)

This is available in Menu `Edit -> Advanced -> Join lines`

Comment: Be aware that this has odd behaviour and a random undesired behaviour (as of v16.8.5):
 the last character(s) on a line joined to is randomly deleted, sometimes more than one character is deleted (multiple characters removed may only occur with older versions);
if the cursor is on the end of line, then the cursor is moved to the next line after the join (really annoying if you are doing multiple joins).

Answer (score 1):

I had been using CodeMaid for this, but it is very slow with large files. To replicate CodeMaid's behaviour with a macro, I've combined Ray Vega's and javs' solutions into the following:

```
    Sub JoinLines()
      DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine()
      DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.WordDeleteToEnd")
      DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Insert(" ")
    End Sub
```

Note: As macros have been dropped in VS2013, I'm using the Visual Commander extension, so the macro actually looks more like:

```
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class C
  Implements VisualCommanderExt.ICommand

  Sub Run(DTE As EnvDTE80.DTE2, package As Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package) Implements VisualCommanderExt.ICommand.Run
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.WordDeleteToEnd")
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Insert(" ")
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the <kbd>End</kbd> and then the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key sequence.

<kbd>End</kbd> moves to the end of the line and the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key removes the EOL
after the cursor.

Comment: This answer ignores the important fact that you want to delete any whitespace leading the second line that gets joined. That's really what is wanted out of a Visual Studio equivalent of Vim's j key.

Comment: This copies the spaces (indentation from next line to the line we are joining. Thus extra spaces.